# Set menu overflow icon to be white

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I have a dummy app that I'm making just to get the hang of Android development. I managed to get a menu overflow icon to appear on my toolbar, but I can't seem to figure out how to change it to white.

I'm using a Toolbar widget (without support libraries; that's something I don't want to do).

Here is what I have:
[image]

I just want to make the overflow menu white.

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want to change `android:textColorSecondary` like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <resources>
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

            <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
            <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
            <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

            <!-- Here you go. This changes overflow icon colour. -->
            <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/WHITE</item>    
        </style>
```

Comment: What else does this color change? Will it have any other side effects?

Comment: From my testing I've found that this only affects those dots.

Comment: Wow. How were we supposed to know that?

Comment: And digging through the AppCompat & AOSP source. Unfortunately style attributes can be quite arcane and unintuitive at times.

Comment: This does work but it also changes the colour of CheckBoxs, at least it did for me anyway

Comment: this will even change the color of Edittext border.

Comment: Horizontal progress bar background colour is also affected. The only reliable solution I could find was explicitly setting it using `Toolbar#setOverflowIcon`

Answer (score 19):

Just add `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" to the toolbar`

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>
```

This thing worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<style name="AppThemeLL" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```